# How to implement setTimeout before blocking while in nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have blocking code like this:

```
let a = 0;
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(a);
    process.exit();
}, 1000);


while (true) {
    a++;
}
```

How can I use `nexttick` function to unblock timeout? Or somethink like this to implement setTimeout before blocking while?

Comment: I would suggest not making a blocking `while` loop in the first place. Consider using callbacks or promises between loop iterations or reviewing why you need to loop this way in the first place

Comment: Can you give me a example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback you register in setTimeout will never be called, since you're blocking the main thread.

You could setInterval to achieve something similar, e.g.

```
let a = 2;
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(a);
    process.exit();
}, 1000);

setInterval(() => {
    // Square a
    a = a * a;
}, 200);
```

Blocking the main thread isn't really a good idea in Node! There's usually a better way to do things in an asynchronous way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, order of execution is important. What about when I want to fire `a = a * a;`

Comment: You can control order of execution by setting the interval length for setInterval and setTimeout, e.g. run setInterval 100 times before setTimeout callback fires once!

Answer (score 0):

Node gets locked when you run synchronous code, meaning if you have a long-running loop it may be helpful to structure it in an asynchronous way so it becomes non-blocking.

```
while(true) { 
   doSomeSyncronousStuff();
}
```

should become something like

```
let someDelay = 0;
let loop = function(continueRunning){
   doSomeSyncronousStuff();
   if(continueRunning) {
      // delay of as little as 0 pushes execution to at least next tick
      setTimeout(loop,someDelay,continueRunning); 
   }
};
loop(true);
```